# Unable to boot Windows after install Ubuntu on a different hard-drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

There were a windows 10 and ubuntu (dual-boot) on my hard drive /dev/sda. I got a new HDD and wanted to move (reinstall) ubuntu to this new HDD or /dev/sdb. So I formatted the old ubuntu on /dev/sda and installed ubuntu /dev/sdb. New ubuntu was installed successfully on /dev/sdb but now I cant boot windows again. On the boot options, there is no choice of windows.

I also tried several guides on the internet (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510013/cant-boot-to-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-in-uefi) but it does not work out and when I ran `sudo update-grub` there is no windows boot. Here is my [Boot Report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hgSJHvw7kB/) from Boot Repair.

Is there anyway to fix this one without reinstalling windows again? I don't want to lose all the data on windows.

Comment: sda is gpt so Windows is installed in UEFI mode.  Looks like you attempted to install Ubuntu in legacy mode on sdb without the necessary grub-bios partition.  Check your machine bios/uefi settings, how the install media boots is how it installs, and install Ubuntu in UEFI mode (then it should find Windows). You should be able to boot Windows now from the EFI menu (some key at powerup), avoiding the broken grub (you deleted necessary grub files when you deleted the sda Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

In 22.04 OS-Prober is disabled. Enable it so Grub can see your Windows installation. 
edit ( as root ) /etc/default/grub
add or uncomment ( place a # in front of the line ) GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false 
save that file then run
`sudo update-grub` or `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.